# Loading URL from API in ngIf and use value again

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

So I hope i can explain it good it enough:

I have an API Call, that I call with id's and it gives me a downloadURL.
Currently I used this as a Promise in my Service:

**In fileClientService:**

```
public async getFile(aID: string, dID: string, sID: string){
    const request: FileRequest = {
      aID: aID,
      dID: dID,
      sID: sID
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.fileService.file(request).subscribe(response => {
        if (response) {
          resolve(response);
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

And in the Controler I have 2 Functions:

**Controler:**

```
  async getDownloadURL(file: FileInfo){
    return await this.fileClientService.getFileTest(file.aID, file.dID, file.sID)
  }

  clickLink(file: FileResponse){
    window.open(file.url)
  }
```

And in the template im trying to load Table Rows and want to check if a donwloadURL is given and its not empty (besause BE can give empty strings back :D)

**Template:**

```
<!-- somewhere above: -->
*ngFor="let entry of period.claims; let i = index"

...

<td>
   <div *ngIf="entry.file">
      <div *ngIf="getDownloadURL(entry.file) | async as file">
         <div *ngIf="file.url !== ''">
            <a target="about:blank" class="download" (click)="clickLink(file)"></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

So what I want to do is:
I want to check if the claim has an entry (*ngIf="entry.file")
If it has one then i want to get the URL (which can take time) and after I got it and when I got it, I want to check if it is an empty string ("") and then it should display the hyperlink with the url.

And I dont want to make an array, that i load at the init with somewhat of a key and the url. Best result for me would be to get the url per row wihtout having to save it in the controler (like the 'as file' in ngIf)

At the moment it calls getDownloadURL infinitely.

I bet there is a better way of doing this. For sure with an Observable or something and I hope you guys can help :)

**UPDATE:**

So for now I changed it to that:

**Service:**

```
getFile(aID: string, dID: string, sID: string){
    const request: FileRequest = {
      aID: aID,
      dID: dID,
      sID: sID
    };
    return this.fileService.file(request).pipe(
      filter(file => file.url.trim() !== '')
   )
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
getDownloadURL(file: FileInfo){
  return this.fileClientService.getFile(file.archiveID, file.documentID, file.sysID)
  }
clickLink(file: FileResponse){
  window.open(file.url)
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngIf="getDownloadURL(entry.file) | async as file; else loading">
   <a target="about:blank" class="download" (click)="clickLink(file)"></a>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>loading..</ng-template>
```

I added the loading Part while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would simplify `getFile` and make it return an `Observable` filtered for non-empty values, like this

```
public getFile(aID: string, dID: string, sID: string){
    const request: FileRequest = {
      aID: aID,
      dID: dID,
      sID: sID
    };
    // assume this.fileService.file returns and Observable
    return this.fileService.file(request).pipe(
       filter(file => file.trim() != '')
    ) 
  }
```

With this version of `getFile` method you should be able to simplify the template like this

```
<td>
      <div *ngIf="getDownloadURL(entry.file) | async as file">
            <a target="about:blank" class="download" (click)="clickLink(file)"></a>
      </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I did that, but it still infinitly loads files and sends requests.
The Call to the API returns an Observable,